# Java GUI JButtons don't work to add or clear isbn and author and window doesn't exit

Tags: java, swing, button, actionlistener

Sorry for such a generic question, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. The jbuttons: submit, clear and exit are not working. Do I need to place the actionListeners somewhere else?

Also, can someone check my code for `submitAction()` used with my submit button? It is almost the last method at the bottom. It should take the book info (isbn & author) submitted from user and save it to book object. I want to be able to search by isbn or author LATER so I need to make sure that the program will identify them separately within book. Thanks for your help in advance!

```
package library.presentation;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import library.domain.Book;

public class AddBooks extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new AddBooks().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();           //north panel
    private JLabel northLabel = new JLabel("");            //north label

    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();          //center panel
    private JPanel bookLabelPanel = new JPanel();           //internal in center panel
    private JLabel[] bookLabel = new JLabel[2];         //create array JLabel
    private String[] bookString = { //create String array
        " ISBN: ", " Author(s): "
    };

    private JPanel bookTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();           //create internal center panel
    private JTextField[] bookTextField = new JTextField[2];         //create array JTextField

    private JPanel submitButtonPanel = new JPanel();            //create internal center panel
    private JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");           //create submit button

    private JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();           //create south panel
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    private JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");           //create exit button

    private Book book;          //create object from other class in actionlistener
    private String[] data;          //create string array to store data

    public boolean isCorrect()          //to check book information in text field
    {
        data = new String[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < bookLabel.length; i++) {
            if (!bookTextField[i].getText().equals("")) {
                data[i] = bookTextField[i].getText();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setText()
    {
        int i = 0;
        bookTextField[i].setText(null);
    }

//constructor of addBooks
    public AddBooks()
    {
        super("Add Books");         //title - internal frame
        Container container = getContentPane();             //GUI components display area
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));            //set layout
        northLabel.setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.BOLD, 16));            //set font - north panel
        northPanel.add(northLabel);             //add label - north panel
        container.add("North", northPanel);             //add north panel to container

        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());          //set layout
        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Add a new book:"));         //set border panel
        bookLabelPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 1, 1, 1));          //set layout

        for (int i = 0; i < bookLabel.length; i++) {        // oop to add strings to labels, set font, add labels to panel
            bookLabelPanel.add(bookLabel[i] = new JLabel(bookString[i]));
            bookLabel[i].setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.BOLD, 12));
        }

        centerPanel.add("West", bookLabelPanel);            //set layout
        bookTextFieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(11, 1, 1, 1));          //set layout

        for (int i = 0; i < bookTextField.length; i++) {       //loop to add string to labels, set font, add labels to panel
            bookTextFieldPanel.add(bookTextField[i] = new JTextField(25));
            bookTextField[i].setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        }

        centerPanel.add("East", bookTextFieldPanel);            //set layout

        submitButtonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));          //set layout
        submitButton.setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.BOLD, 12));          //set font
        submitButtonPanel.add(submitButton);            //add submit button
        centerPanel.add("South", submitButtonPanel);            //add submit button panel
        container.add("Center", centerPanel);       //add to container

        southPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));         //set layout
        exitButton.setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.BOLD, 12));            //set font
        clearButton.setFont(new Font("Book Antigua", Font.BOLD, 12));            //set font
        southPanel.add(clearButton);         //add clear button
        southPanel.add(exitButton);         //add exit button
        southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());       //set border
        container.add("South", southPanel);         //add to container

        setVisible(true);
        pack();

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void submitAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                try {
                    String isbn = null;
                    String author = null;
                    int i = 0;
                    Book book = new Book(isbn, author);
                    book.setIsbn(bookTextField[i].getText());
                    book.setAuthor(bookTextField[i].getText());
                    book.setText(isbn + "" + author);
                    System.out.println("You have submitted a book! " + book.toString());
                    // Book -> BookMgr.storeBook;           //code to pass to BookMgr

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });

        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void clearAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                try {
                    setText();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void exitAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }

        });

    }       //end of constructor
}       //end of class AddBooks
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `exitAction`, `clearAction`, or `submitAction` are never called. On a click, only a `JButton`'s `ActionListener`'s `actionPerformed` method will be called, as it serves as the callback function/observer function for the click event.

The solution here is easy though, have the corresponding `actionPerformed` method simply call one of the three methods you created. In addition, it would probably would be best to move the three methods outside the ActionListeners and into `AddBooks` as they operate on `AddBooks` data.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    submitAction(); // doesn't look like ActionEvent needs to be a parameter.
}
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested but it didn't work, so I just replaced the 'exitAction', etc with actionPerformed and kept them with each ActionListener and they are doing something now. However, I don't think my code for my submit button is correct and my clear button is only clearing the first bookTextField which is the isbn. Any ideas to fix these 2 problems?

Comment: I got the clearing issue fix, just need help with adding the user submitted text to save to book in the submitButton actionPerformed method.

Comment: @user2719471 In your submit method, you are not saving the local `Book` instance created anywhere. Perhaps you wanted to modify an existing instance instead of creating a new one?

Comment: is that a question or suggestion? :)  here is what I need it to do it exactly, I forgot that it should pass to BookMgr:  user-supplied information to be packaged into a domain Book object. It will also:
o Pass the domain Book object to the BookMgr.storeBook function.
o Display the state of the Book using its overridden toString() method; e.g System.out.println(book.toString());

Comment: @user2719471 It sounds like you need to store the local Book instance off to that book manager class you mention, that would match up well to your existing code comments at the end of your submit function.

Comment: To be more clear, I need to pass Book from library.domain.AddBooks to library.business.BookMgr to a storeBook function.